# Stop sidebar from scrolling on y-axis

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar in my code which I got from [here](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/). When the content of the page is too long, the body will scroll but the sidebar does not.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4694/)

This is how I would like mine to work, but because I have a header, I get this nasty effect seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4695/).

HTML:

```
<title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>
<body>
    <!--Header-->
    <div id="header-content-wrapper" class="as-header-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="header" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7 panel">
                    <span>This is heading text!!!</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper" class="">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand"> <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Dashboard</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Overview</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Events</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">About</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Services</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Contact</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                         <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>

                        <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p> <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>

                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                      Hellow
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.as-header-wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Toggle Styles */
 #wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}
/* Sidebar Styles */
 .sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }
    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

If I could keep the sidebar from scrolling with the content (like setting the `position: absolute;` in `sidebar-wrapper`) and keep the height of the sidebar matching the content, I think would work okay.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs some fixes in the css sheet ...

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    overflow-y:none; //THIS -> ADD
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    max-width:100%;  //THIS -> ADD
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right:-250px; //THIS -> REMOVE
}
```

EDIT :

After few tests, here is what you try to do : http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4759/

But there are few problems to fix with style when you're on a small screen... menu style seems to change (to white background instead of black) and some other problems...

This is all about css "position" and sizes... but here is a good starting point i think.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm afraid this isn't quite what I'm looking for, I would like to stop the nav bar from scrolling, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4717/)

Comment: I just don't understand what's wrong... even with your link... the navbar (left) does not scroll^^ pls give more details...

Comment: You want to keep your sidebar in the up left corner of the wrapper? when you scroll down you want your navbar to stay up?  (and so it will not be visible when you go to the bottom of page?)

Comment: Yeah, I would like if the navbar would stay up in the left corner. And when I scroll down, you can still see the sidebar colour on the left.

Comment: This is closer to what you want to do but i actually don't get why this doesnt work properly with some screen sizes... http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4740/

Comment: check my answer update, here is a starting point to get what you want.